# Databricks user account details

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

there are few users added in Databricks who are able to run notebooks, clusters etc. How do I find when those users were created?

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't exposed through [SCIM Users API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-users), so the only way to find it is to look into [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/azure-diagnostic-logs) if it was enabled before users were created, and logs aren't older than retention time in the Log Analytics.